# Flutter Status Color change

Tags: flutter

How do I change the color of the status value came from database if pending turns to red and if done it turns to green

I have a value in my database pending and done if the status shown their is pending the status color in my flutter will be red and if its done the color will be green

```
final x = list[i];
debugPrint(x.toString());
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Vessel Name:\t' + x["vesselname"],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Text('Ship Call #:\t' + x["scn"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            Text('Vessel Number:\t' + x["voyageno"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            Text('Status:\t' + x["status"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            Divider()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Here is my request to the database:

```
var url = "http://192.168.1.15/vessellog/read.php";
  List<dynamic> list = [];
  Future<void> getData() async {
    list.clear();
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences preferences = await _prefs;
    String id = preferences.getString("id");
    final response = await http.get(url + "?client_signature=$id");
    debugPrint(response.body);
    if (response.contentLength == 2) {
    } else
      setState(() {
        list = jsonDecode(response.body);
        loading = false;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to use the color argument from TextStyle. Change it based on the `loading` value.

Here is your full code with this small change, see commented line:

```
final x = list[i];
debugPrint(x.toString());
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Vessel Name:\t' + x["vesselname"],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Text('Ship Call #:\t' + x["scn"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            Text('Vessel Number:\t' + x["voyageno"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            Text(
              'Status:\t' + x["status"],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: loading ? Colors.red : Colors.green, // isPending is the value from your database
              ),
            ),
            Divider()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: yes pending and done  actually my project is web and mobile when the user in the web updated the status into done the color  in the text will change into green when done and red when its pending

Comment: So does this solve your answer? If not please explain why.

Comment: i had a undefined pending

Comment: You have to define isPending based on the status value from your database

Comment: how sir sorry im new at flutter

Comment: Well I don't know which database you are using so I can't tell you that

Comment: im using phpmyadmin

Comment: yes but the color of pending is green it must be red

Comment: Isn't this what you want ? Red while loading then green. If you don't see the red maybe it's loading too fast for you to see

Comment: no what i mean is if the status value is pending the color of the pending text status is red when it is updated in to the database done it will turn into green cause i had a enum value in my database pending and done

Comment: I'm sorry it appears I can't understand what you want. I hope someone else will.

Comment: i will add a picture wait